# Magento 1.9 How to show upsell products in carousel?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, up-sells

I want to show upsell products in  carousel. Anyone can you help me?

> My working domain URL : http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/rilon-arc-200t.html

Comment: are you talking about lightSlider ?

Comment: yes, like this : http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have an issue of `javascript` loading sequence.

Load `jquery_noconflict.js` before `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` then load `lightslider.js` after `jquery-2.2.3.min.js`.

Also I found this script `$(document).ready(function() {$("#content-slider").lightSlider({ loop:true, keyPress:true }); });` but there is no elemenet with `id = content-slider`.

Comment: i was used in home page to display a random products, it will works well. The same code i was using to display a upsell products, it will show blank page. I called all the css and js files.

Comment: Please study JS load sequence of both the pages. In homepage there's a `jquery.min.js` before `lightslider.js` while in product view page there's NO `jquery.min.js`

Comment: now i was update the code, now you can see what it return.

Comment: http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/rilon-arc-200t.html

Comment: nothing changed there. Also JS are loaded as it was before. It's not showing upsells as well

Comment: i think there was some problem to load upsell products

Comment: my default upsell code was up here, pls reload it

Comment: now try the solution provided

Comment: @Vijayakumar: does this helps ?

Answer (score 0):

Using light slider, add light slider css file in header of the document. Try to find the light slider css and js from internet.

```
<div class="demo">
<ul id="responsive" class="content-slider">
<li><!-- upsell product display code --></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src='filepath/lightslider.js'></script>
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.content-slider').lightSlider({
            auto: true, item:6, loop:true, keyPress:true,
            slideMove:2,
            easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
            speed:600,
            responsive : [
                {
                    breakpoint:800,
                    settings: {
                        item:2,
                        slideMove:1,
                        slideMargin:6,
                      }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint:480,
                    settings: {
                        item:1,
                        slideMove:1
                      }
                }
            ]
        });  
      });
</script>
```